# Анимирование по окружности при нажатии

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я пытаюсь написать небольшую логику для моих сфер: сфера, которая имеет угол PI/2, активна и имеет цвет красный. При нажатии на сферу( не активную ) она должна переместиться плавно по окружности на угол PI/2 следующим образом:

1. если эта сфера слева, то она смещается вправо на угол PI/2 и становится активной; сфера, что была на PI/2 смещается вправо на угол PI/6, а та сфера, что была на PI/6 смещается вправо в ускоренном темпе и становится на место той, которая была слева ( 5PI/6 )
2. если эта сфера справа, то все наоборот ( смещение влево )

Главная проблема заключается в сравнении X и Y - `this.left !== left(this.alpha + Math.PI / 3) && this.top !== topF(this.alpha + Math.PI / 3)`. Как правильно здесь сравнивать или вычислять координаты для смещения сферы или может я не правильно увеличиваю `time`?

Мой код:

```js
//Circles position
let circle = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');
let radius = 100;
let direction;

class Circle {
  constructor(element) {
    this.$el = element.selector;
    this.alpha = element.alpha;
    this.left = left(this.alpha);
    this.top = topF(this.alpha);
    this.$el.style.left = this.left + 'px';
    this.$el.style.top = this.top + 'px';
    this.activated = element.activated;
    this.run = false;
    this.time = 0;
  }
  moveIn() {
    this.run = true;
    this.animate();
  }
  animation() {
    this.run = true;
    if ( this.left > left( Math.PI / 2 ) ){
      direction = "left";
    } else {
      direction = "right";
    }
    this.animate();
  }
  animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
    if (this.run) {
      if ( direction === "left" ){
        this.time += Math.PI / 90;
        this.moveLeft();
      } else {
        this.time += Math.PI / 90;
        this.moveRight();
      }
    }
  }
  moveLeft(){
    if (this.left !== left(this.alpha + Math.PI / 3)
        && this.top !== topF(this.alpha + Math.PI / 3) ) {

      this.left = left(this.alpha + this.time);
      this.top = topF(this.alpha + this.time);
      this.$el.style.left = this.left + 'px';
      this.$el.style.top = this.top + 'px';
    } else {
      this.time = 0;
      return cancelAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    }
  }
  moveRight() {
    if (this.left !== left(this.alpha - Math.PI / 3)
        && this.top !== topF(this.alpha - Math.PI / 3) ) {

      this.left = left(this.alpha - this.time);
      this.top = topF(this.alpha - this.time);
      this.$el.style.left = this.left + 'px';
      this.$el.style.top = this.top + 'px';

    } else {
      this.time = 0;
      return cancelAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    }
  }

}
let c1 = new Circle({
  selector: circle[0],
  alpha: Math.PI / 6,
  activated: false
})
let c2 = new Circle({
  selector: circle[1],
  alpha: Math.PI / 2,
  activated: true
})
let c3 = new Circle({
  selector: circle[2],
  alpha: (Math.PI / 6) * 5,
  activated: false
})

circle[0].addEventListener('click', clicked);
circle[1].addEventListener('click', clicked);
circle[2].addEventListener('click', clicked);

function clicked(e) {
  let id = e.target.id;
  if ( id === 'c1' && !c1.activated ){
    this.activated = true;
    c2.activated = false;
    c3.activated = false;
    c1.animation();
    c2.moveIn();
    c3.moveIn();
  }
  else if ( id === 'c2' && !c2.activated ){
    this.activated = true;
  }
  else if ( id === 'c3' && !c3.activated){
    this.activated = true;

  }
}

function left(alpha) {
   return 90 + radius * Math.cos(alpha);
}
function topF(alpha) {
    return 90 + radius * Math.sin(-alpha);
}
```

```css
.cMain{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    top: calc(100% + 145px);
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);

    background-color: #060505;
    border: 5px solid #2D2D2D46;
    z-index: 1;
}
.circle{
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;

    background-color: fuchsia;
}
#c1{
  background-color: red;
}
#c2{
  background-color: blue;
}
#c3{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cMain">
  <div class="circle" id="c1">

  </div>
  <div class="circle" id="c2">

  </div>
  <div class="circle" id="c3">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы поворачиваете сами точки, но смысла в этом особого нет. Можно все точки обернуть во врапер, сам врапер сделать по размерам основного круга. Далее при помощи `transform: rotate()` врапер вращать на нужный угол - это значительно удобней, т.к. не требуется считать фактические координаты.

Далее нужно определить в какой позиции находятся точки (какая левей, какая правей), направление поворота (если эвент произошел правей активной точки, то налево, если слева от активной, значит вправо) и применить угол поворота к точкам.

Скорость вращения можно задать в css `transition`

В целом, смотрите пример с подробными комментариями ниже.

```js
const initialRadius = 100;
const angles = {
  initial: [300, 0, 60], //углы инициализации
  
  //Маска поворота
  rotate: {
    right: [60, 60, 240], //право
    left: [-240, -60, -60] //лево
  }
}

//инициализируем клавный круг, присваиваем ему высоту и ширину
const cMain = document.querySelector('.cMain');
cMain.style.height = `${initialRadius*2}px`;
cMain.style.width = `${initialRadius*2}px`;


//Ф-я создания враппера, который будем вращать
const createDotWrapper = () => {
  let circle = document.createElement('div');
  circle.classList.add('dotWrapper');

  //задаем ширину и высоту исходя из базового радиуса.
  circle.style.height = `${initialRadius*2}px`;
  circle.style.width = `${initialRadius*2}px`;

  //позиционируем по центру основного круга
  circle.style.left = `calc(50% - ${initialRadius}px)`;
  circle.style.bottom = `calc(50% - ${initialRadius}px)`;
  circle.appendChild(createDot())

  return circle;
}

//ф-я создания точки
const createDot = () => {
  let dot = document.createElement('div');
  dot.classList.add('dot');
  return dot;
}

//ф-я переназначения активной точки.
const setActive = (element) => {
  document.querySelector('.dot-active').classList.remove('dot-active');
  element.classList.add('dot-active');
}

//ф-я поворота 
const rotate = (eventCoordinatesX) => {
  //определяем направление поворота
  let direction = (document.querySelector('.dot-active').getBoundingClientRect().left - eventCoordinatesX) > 0 ? 'right' : 'left';
  
  //ищем все точки, определяем в массив, сортируем массив слева направо, в зависимости от их положения по оси x (самая левая точка будет первой в массиве и т.д.), это нужно, чтобы наложить маску поворота.
  let dots = Array.from(cMain.querySelectorAll('.dot')).sort((a,b)=>(a.getBoundingClientRect().left < b.getBoundingClientRect().left) ? -1 : 1)
  
  //перебираем точки, применяем к врапперу (родитель) маску поворота в порядке очерди, в зависимости от направления.
  dots.forEach((dot, index)=>{
    //извлекаем текущий угол поворота.
    let actualAngle = Number(dot.parentNode.style.getPropertyValue("transform").match('-?[0-9]+'))
    //новый угол
    let newAngle = actualAngle + angles.rotate[direction][index];
    //применяем новый угол к родителю
    dot.parentNode.style.transform = `rotate(${newAngle}deg)`
  })
}


/*Начинаем рисовать*/

//Создаем точки, учитываем, что поворачиваем мы .circle;
angles.initial.map((angle, index) => {
  let circle = createDotWrapper();
  circle.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg)`;
  // установим дефолтный активный элемент
  (angle==0) && circle.querySelector('.dot').classList.add('dot-active')
  //если надо, то точкам можно айдишники назначить, в работе они не используются.
  //circle.querySelector('.dot').setAttribute('id', `dot-${index}`)
  cMain.appendChild(circle);
})

//Назначение обработки нажатия
cMain.querySelectorAll('.dot').forEach((dot, index)=>{
  dot.onclick = (event) => {
    //Скипаем, если кликнули по активному
    if (dot.classList.contains('dot-active'))
      return
    rotate(event.pageX);
    setActive(dot);
  }
})
```

```css
.cMain {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #2D2D2D46;
  background: #060505;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dotWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform .5s linear;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.dot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  /*Позиционируем на 12 часов*/
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 999;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.dot-active {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="cMain"></div>
```